# play multiple mp3 files with delay

Tags: android

I need the method that my app run multiple mp3s. Each mp3 must play after previous mp3.
I created method that play sound

```
void PlaySentence(String path){
    try {            
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(path);
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAGName, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then I call that function in OnCreate. I used while loop for playing all mp3 files. But sound mixed to each other. If I use loops and isPlaying method the application didn't respond.

```
while (currentMp3<totalMp3) {
if (!player.isPlaying()) {
            PlaySentence();
        }
}
```

Also I use below method for avoid of mixing sounds. It work for one mp3

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    PlaySentence();
                }
            });
```

What is the best solution to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setOnCompletionListener, but declare your player as a class member, initalize it in onCreate, and don't create a new one for each mp3. PlaySentence should be something as:

```
void PlaySentence(String path){
try {            
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(path);
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAGName, ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: Having  try/catch block for catch the base clas "Exception" is usually a bad idea. It will hide real bugs. Instead catch the exception subclasses that you know can actually happen. Having built an Android mediaplayer app, the only area where I needed a try/catch block was around `setDataSource`. Specific exceptions caught were `IllegalArgumentException`, `SecurityException`, `IllegalStateException`, and `IOException`. And if you hook up all the callbacks to MediaPlayer to monitor the object's state, you shouldn't ever have to worry about IllegalStateException if you do it right.